# Best way to check if content of page has been changed?

Tags: php, python, hash, web-crawler

I have a crawler that crawl hundred of thousands of pages and index/parse the contents of the page, and one thing I'm struggling with is to check if the content of a page has been updated, in an efficient way, without having to crawl it and check the content of the page.

Obviously I could just load the whole page, and re-parse everything and compare it all to what I have stored in my database. However that is very inefficient and use a lot of computing resulting in high hosting bills.

I'm thinking of comparing hashes, the problem with this is that if the page has changed a single byte or character, the hash would be different. So for example if the page display the current date on the page, every single time the hash would be different and tell me that the content has been updated.

So... How would you do this? Would you look at the kb size of the HTML? Would you look at the string length and check if for example the length has changed more than 5%, the content has been "changed"? Or is there some kind of hashing algoritm where the hashes stay the same if only small parts of the string/content has been changed?

Comment: Is the `last-modified` header (or optionally, `ETag`) reliable on the site you're scraping?  If so, just use that.

Comment: ... and use a `HEAD` http request. Not a plain `GET`.

Comment: Im crawling many different kind of domains and sites and we are scaling up to new domains aswell. So a method that is reliable on all domains would be preferable.

Comment: About `last-modified` - unfortunately not all servers return this date correctly. I think it is not reliable solution. I think better way - combine hash and content length solution. Check hash, and if it changed - check string length.

Comment: About content length - you can try strip all tags and check string length after then. In this case you can forgot about HTML changes. Also you can replace all consecutive spaces to one, to prevent it effect to hash

Comment: How about a two step process?  You could use hashes to screen for pages that might have changed.  If the hashes match, the page is unchanged.  If not, you can parse to determine whether the change was significant.  This should be decently efficient as long as there are not too many false positives (i.e. changed hashes without a real change in content).

Answer (score 2):

You could try and use the value contained in the "last-mofidied" header in the response from the server. Parsing this into a nice object would allow for simple date comparisons, letting you check if you should re-scrape. For example (in Python using the brilliant [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/) library:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Python')
site_last_modified_date = r.headers["Last-Modified"]

# from here, just parse the date and compare it with the last recorded date
```

Comment: Unfortunately not all servers return this date correctly. I think it is not reliable solution

Comment: Thank you for your answer but as I stated in the comments earlier, since we crawl many different servers and domains we want to find a more reliable solution that works everywhere.